# How to import an excel workbook into jupyterr notebook

Tags: pandas, tensorflow

How do I import an excel workbook into jupyter notebook. I am using tensorflow.

```
  xl.file =pd.excelfile('c:\users\owner\downloads\book1.xlsx')
  book1 = pd.excelfile('book1.xlsx')
```

Comment: You're using pandas not tensor flow use  `pd.read_excel(path_to_file)` also what kind of object is `xl.file` ?

Comment: Hi. Please briefly describe your problem. Are you getting an error? The code stops without an error but does not give your expected output? What's your expected output? Also, `tensorflow` is not relevant with importing an Excel file into jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing the filename with the pandas method to read a file.

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'c:\users\owner\downloads\book1.xlsx'
dataframe = pd.read_excel(filename)
```